# Windows inf file for an USB device

Tags: usb, pid, inf

What does mean MI_00 in the following line in Windows' inf-file:

%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_28FA&PID_8036&MI_00

?

It looks like if I remove it, the device cannot be re-installed any more.
h

Answer (score 4):

Interface descriptors, i.e. MI_xx, is a grouping of endpoints for USB devices with multiple interfaces. Have a look at [this chapter](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml) in USB In a Nutshell which explains interface descriptors, or take a look at section Multiple-interfaces device in [this MSDN text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-device-layout).